# Naming a new list from another list in Python

Tags: python, list

this may sound like a strange question from a Python noob, but here's the deal.  I have a list with a bunch of (string) entries.  I want to take one of those entries, add another string to the end of it, and then create a new array with that name.  Eg, I have

```
list=["foo","bar"]
```

and I want to get something to the effect of

```
fooblah = []
```

I've been trying to do it this way

```
list[0] + "blah" = []
```

Obviously this doesn't work because the first part is a string instead of a variable name, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  From what I've read of other people's problems, the solution might be in using a dictionary instead (?), but to be honest I'm not really sure how dictionaries work yet.

Thanks, J.

Comment: You can think of a dictionary as a type that maps one thing to another -- just like a real dictionary maps words to their definitions. You still access elements through the `[ ]` operator just like arrays, except that the keys don't have to be integers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a python [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) they can use practically anything as an index instead of integers.  You're code could get messy and unreadable really fast if you are dynamically creating local / global variables.

For example

```
l = ["foo","bar"]
d = {}
d[l[0] + "blah"] = []
d[l[0] + "blah"].append("foo")
```

Using a dictionary will give you some other neat advantages, for example, you can loop through all of the new lists you create.

```
for k,v in d.iteritems():
    print "{0} --> {1}".format(k,v)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you really want to do this one way would be through the [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals) or `locals()` methods which return a dictionary of the current symbols:

```
globals()[list[0] + 'blah'] = [  ]
```

Note that `list` is the name of a built-in type, so using it as your variable name is considered bad practice.

Also, this is a highly unusual need; what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it's not actually the variable name; I was just using it as an example (obviously not a very good one).  Basically I have a list of all the directories in a folder, each one named for a different exposure.  If the directory has a certain file in it, I want to read that whole file into a new array, but to keep each exposure separate it would be nice if that new array could somehow be named in a way that lets me know which exposure it came from. Is there a better way?  I don't doubt it, but like I said I'm pretty new at this.

Comment: @JustinS: Definitely a case for dictionaries (see GWW's answer). The exposure folder name could be the key, with the file contents as the value (if I interpreted correctly). Then you could do all sorts of nice things with the dictionary that you couldn't with variables, such as loop over them easily.

Comment: Yup, that's what we're going to go with.  Thanks for your and @GWW 's advice.